# Run and "end" sink from within a function

Tags: r

I want to use sink within a function.

Lets create a file to have a reproducible example:

```
write.table("stop('error message')", "sampleError.R")
```

First a working example - outside a function:

```
con <- file("test.log")
sink(con, append = TRUE)
sink(con, append = TRUE, type="message")

source("sampleError.R", echo = TRUE, max.deparse.length = 10000)

sink() 
sink(type = "message")

logFile <- readLines("test.log")
```

Now the fail attempt to call it in a function. The fail is that the recording is not finihsed and the `sink()` commands have to be called outside the function to finalize the log creation.

```
f <- function(){
  con <- file("test.log")
  sink(con, append = TRUE)
  sink(con, append = TRUE, type="message")

  source(filePath, echo = TRUE, max.deparse.length = 10000)

  sink() 
  sink(type = "message")

  logFile <- readLines("test.log")
}
f()
```

And yes, unfortunately i have to insist on calling it from a function ;)

Comment: What do you mean by "fail"? Did it throw you an error? Did it not capture what you want into the log file? _How_ did it fail?

Comment: i made an edit: "The fail is that the recording is not finihsed and the `sink()` commands have to be called outside the function to finalize the log creation." If you run the code, it might be more easy to understand what i mean. Thanks for your time!